# Use NSInteger as array index

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

Have a happy year!

I am having trouble with the following. First logic:

Get json from server. Json value is always a number. Read plist into array. NSLog the array with index of the json value from server.

**My plist:**

```
Key     Type     Value
Item 0  String   New York
Item 1  String   Atlanta
```

**My code:**

**Get Json**

```
NSString *url_req=@"http://domain.com/index.php";

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_req]];

            NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:nil error:nil];

            NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                      options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

            NSArray *cityArray = [json objectForKey:@"city"];
            for (NSDictionary *alert in pestoArray ){
                myLoc = [[alert objectForKey:@"location"] integerValue];
            }
```

Json is working just fine!

**Read plist and nslog the corresponding value:**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"townsList" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSArray *arrayNo= [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];            
 NSLog(@"City %@",arrayNo[myLoc]);
```

So far `arrayNo[myLoc]` will return null but `arrayNo[1]` will return Atlanta.

How can i use the integer value from JSON as an array index?

Thank you!

EDIT: Error output when using `arrayNo[myLoc]` is

```
Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') is not an integral or Objective-C pointer type
```

Comment: What is the value of myLoc? And where do you declare it? What is its type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the error message, you declared `myLoc` as a pointer to an NSInteger (`NSInteger *myLoc`) rather than an actual NSInteger (`NSInteger myLoc`). It needs to be the latter.