# Error: indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'char *(*)(const char *, int)' is not an integral or OBjective-C pointer type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple drawRandom card method...which will return a pointer to a card

-(Card *)drawRandomCard{

```
Card * randomCard = nil;
if ([self.cards count]){
unsigned index = arc4random_uniform ([self.cards count]);
//return it
randomCard = self.cards[index]; // if I return randomCard I won't get an error!
[self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
return self.cards[index];
```

}

-If I write my code as such, I get the error mentioned.

-If I return randomCard instead, I won't get any error.

-I tried changing index to NSInteger, int, NSUInteger, but none worked.

-Though only thing that worked for me was to define my index as a pointer, like this `@property (nonatomic,assign) NSUInteger index`. **I can't understand why that helps and also I think I should be able to do it the way I intended to do.**

---

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928930/error-indexing-expression-is-invalid-because-subscript-type-nsuinteger-is-not) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863859/use-nsinteger-as-array-index) question, but the problem their was that their index was not a primitive type, rather it was a pointer, but my index here is an int, so I am still confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index` in the return statement isn't in the same scope as your `index` in the if statement.  It's a pointer to the global function `index()` which isn't a valid subscript.

Making `index` a property works because it pulls it out to a scope where your return can see it.

Comment: :] Thanks! Does that mean using index as a variable name is sort of a bad practice, to avoid such issues.

Comment: I wouldn't say its bad practice, you just have to be careful to understand the scope of your variables when you are shadowing existing ones.  ObjC has a lot of random functions it inherits from C sitting around that you have to step around occasionally.